# How to design a lstm with different time step in input and target with keras

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I'm new to keras and trying to use lstm to predict an annual vegetation index based on climate data with finer time steps. I'm not sure how to build a correct neural network to do the prediction.

For example, I have 30 years monthly climate data. The data contain 5 variables (monthly temperature, precipitation, VPD, radiation, humidity). So the input structure should be like [1,30*12,5]. While for the target, I only have one value for a year, i.e., [1,30,1]. How could I tell the algorithm that I only have one value for a year? Any useful functions for this kind of cases?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So let me get this straight - you have monthly climate observations, but for labels you only have a single record per year? Well, you either need to get more vegetation indices to match your climate data or you'd need to average out your climate data on a yearly scale, but then you'll have too few data points to train the model on.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply! Yes the dataset would be too small once averaged into annual values. So that means it is difficult to work with this many-to-one situation based on Keras? Any other solutions to deal with the situation?